# MAUI DisplayAlert() When User Closes Window : Getting Unhandled Exception

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

I want to show an ALERT/POPUP to the user to ask him/her before he closes the Application.

This is what I am already doing :

In `App.xaml.cs`

`Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert` this line throws unhandled exception,

**The Exception gets unhandled by debugger itself**. and it says :

> a debugger is attached to but not configured to debug this unhandled
> exception.

https://github.com/BhangeeF16/MAUI-DOT-NET/blob/main/SampleApp/App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static IServiceProvider Services;

    public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Services = serviceProvider;
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
        window.Page = MainPage;
        window.Destroying += Window_Destroying;
        return window;
    }

    private void Window_Destroying(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Destroying");
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Are you sure you want to close the application.", "Yes", "No"));    
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Comment: I read the documentation, implemented an override for it, the issue now is that I cant get the alert to show. @monstertjie_za

Comment: It's impossible to pop up an alert from a closed window, the handle will not be valid. Please be noted that `the destroy event` is for releasing resources.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you read and understand the life cycle of an MAUI app:
[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle)

The event you are looking for should either be OnStopped, or OnDestroying, dependant on your needs.

Comment: I read the documentation, implemented an override for it, the issue now is that I cant get the alert to show. Every time I try to show an Alert it throws an exception @monstertjie_za

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to intercept and use the window after the process of destroying has already commenced.
In general, you wont easily be able to intercept the ending of your application because a user can swipe the window away and there is nothing you can do about it.

But to be more complete, it is possible on WinUI to use platform specific code in order to intercept the WM_CLOSE message and then display a confirmation dialog before the destroy event is ever triggered.
This is done by extending your `MauiAppBuilder` `ConfigureLifecycleEvents` and handling the `OnPlatformMessage` looking for `MessageId` = 0x0010 which is `WM_CLOSE`

fwiw, most of this is in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle) you *claimed* to have read...

```
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;

namespace PlatformLifecycleDemo
{
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
#if WINDOWS
                events.AddWindows(windows => windows.OnPlatformMessage((window, args) =>
                       {
                           if (args.MessageId == Convert.ToUInt32("0010", 16))
                           {
                               // Window close request
                           }
                       }));
#endif
                });

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```